# Where does the block variable in create_table come from in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rails generate model User email:string password:string
```

Looking into the migration that was created:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

From the book "Beginning Rails 4": "This is a standard migration fare. In the change definition, you use create_table method to create a new users table. **The new table object is *yielded* to the block variable t**, on which you call the string method to create each column"

I'd like a more detailed explanation of exactly where the block variable t comes from. Is it returned by the create_table method (I think not, but I can't think of anything else)?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
# create_table() passes a TableDefinition object to the block.
# This form will not only create the table, but also columns for the
# table.
```

So the `t` you are seeing is actually an object of the `TableDefinition` class.  You can read more about this class here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html

Comment: This is the answer I think

Answer (score 0):

A block is what you see between the `do` and the `end`. The block variable in this case was declared here `create_table :users do |t|` between the `|` in that line.